# the argument type 'list<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string?'. In document snapShot flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the problem with updating the documentUid as in array at the same time which I get a snapShot from here
`var userDocumentUid = snapshot.data?["membersUid"];` But it says list' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string?'. Here `.doc(userDocumentUid??[])`

Full code:

```
    StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("groups")
                  .doc(groupId)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              //get array snapShot as show in img
              var userDocumentUid = snapshot.data?["membersUid"];

            return...


                     ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async => await firestore
                                  .collection("users")
                               //problem here
                                  .doc(userDocumentUid??[])
                                  .update({
                                'counts': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['1'])
                              }),
```

Img: [image]

Update 'counts' of both users using userDocumentUid at the same time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, doc() requires a **String** value and you're passing whole array i.e. userDocumentUid. You should pass with index like **userDocumentUid[index]**.

Secondly, You're using null aware operator in doc(userDocumentUid??[]) and passing an empty array if userDocumentUid[index] is null.. That's wrong. You should make sure to pass a **non-nullable userDocumentUid[index]**. if you replace [] with "", this error will no come again but will come something like no document to update if **userDocumentUid[index]** is null.

Answer (score 0):

please check whether userDocumentId(list) should be passed as a json or not.

because **json.encode(anything) gives you string** and we can pass it as json like

```
.doc(json.encode(userDocumentId??[]))
```